# How to move parent with hundreds of children smoothly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a bubble shooter game. In one level, I have about 500 bubbles inside their parent. Now, I want to move all of them up or down smoothly on Android.

Profiler in PC:
+ Draw call: 18
+ FPS : 800
=> Very smooth on PC.

Device: Nexus 4
Profiler in Android:
+ Draw call: 18
+ FPS from 30 to 60

Because the fps on Android is not stable (30 - 60), this causes the moving not smoothly as I expected. Please take a look at my Android Profiler.

[image]

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are aware that mobile devices are still many, many times slower than any desktop computer, right? From the profiler screenshot it seems graphics/rendering is where most of the time goes, so consider reducing the visual complexity of your app. Other than that, without seeing any code whatsoever, no further suggestions can be made.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I only use tranform.position += .... for moving the parent. Nothing more. Beside that, I don't understand why camera.render takes too much different times for each frame. This causes lag (or shake, not smooth) when moving the parent. As you can see, there is not too many game objects in my scene, right? And Nexus 4 is a device with good performance I think.

Comment: But you have 500 active bubbles. Each bubble adds some overhead even if they're not currently visible on the screen. And 500 objects on a mobile device, especially if they have physics on them (?), it can be quite taxing. This needs further analysis or at least trial and error (try removing 400 objects, see if that helps).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I don't have any components in bubbles except sprite renderer. I tried to remove 400 objects but the game is still shake when moving. Thanks for your help and any other advices? :")

Comment: Are you using Time.deltaTime when moving bubbles?. This is the way to make the movement independent of fps.

Comment: @JordiC : I tried to use a lot of translating types such as: 
(1). Vector3 move toward  
(2). transform.position += Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime  
(3).  transform.position += Vector3.up * Time.fixeddeltaTime (in FixedUpdate)
(4). use itween.

But all of them don't fix my problem :((

Comment: Too many bubbles is the problem. Also, those are some pretty graphics!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of moving GameObjects (bubbles), I think it should be better to move the Camera:

Camera.main.gameObject.transform.position += delta * Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime;

Comment: This is also what I thought before. However, in my opinion, it needs 2 camera to make it work. One is the main camera (show the background, dragon .... These things can not move like bubbles)  and the other move to see the moving bubbles effect. And I don't know where to begin. How can I combine two cameras ... ?

Comment: You can use layers. Assign different layers to background, dragon,... and bubbles. Then add a new camera and in every camera use "culling mask" property to assign layers to this camera

Comment: I feel a little bit promising right now. Let me try it within 15 minutes and I'll come back :). Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I tried it. I make the new camera move and the game still shake (lag). I reduce the number of bubbles to 100 but nothing changes. :((